# How to return Eloquent models' single column values as an array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In Laravel is it possible to select only one field and return that as a set/ array.

For example consider the model `Foo` which is linked to table `foos` which has field `id`, `a`, `b`, `c`.

Consider the following sample data:

```
(1, 10, 15, 20)
(1, 12, 15, 27)
(1, 17, 15, 27)
(1, 25, 16, 29)
(1, 28, 16, 40)
```

Now if I wanted to create a query that returns all the values of `a` where `b` is `15`, I could do that like so:

```
Foo::select('a')->where('b', 15)->get();
```

However this will return an eloquent collection.

Instead how can I return instead an array like this:

```
[10, 12, 17]
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Just use `pluck()` and `->toArray()`:

```
Foo::where('b', 15)->pluck('a')->toArray();
```

[Laravel's pluck() method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-pluck).

[Laravel's toArray() method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-toarray).

Comment: but dosen't that return an associative array?

Comment: Yes you have to use pluck() to select one specific column. I edited my answer

Comment: Just tried it and it works the way you want with pluck (or lists because lists() is an alias of pluck()) and toArray()

Comment: new knowledge to me..tq :)

Answer (score 4):

Do

```
Foo::where('b', 15)->lists('a')->all();
```

This will give you an array of ids. eg [2, 3, 5]

Comment: what does `lists` and `all` mean

Comment: **lists** will convert the result to a collection and **all** will make it an array. but with laravel 4 you can only use **lists** and it will convert your result to an array.

Comment: so can't i also write `Foo::select('a')->where('b', 15)->all();`
`

Comment: No. With what you want you can't use select and all. You will get a collection instead. but if you change the all to get()->toArray() you will get an associative array. So the best is to use **lists** and **all**

Comment: @YahyaUddin The `lists` method is just an alias for [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-pluck) as @Mushr00m very well exemplified in his answer. The Laravel Documentation explains clearly [what methods a Collection offers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#available-methods) and what they do.

Comment: You shouldn't use lists anymore as a it's depricated and will be removed in future versions, use pluck() instead.

Answer (score 4):

The lists method is deprecated and pluck need some parameter so, if you want to get all the attributed in array format, use it this way.

`Foo::select('a')->where('b', 15)->get()->all();`

Comment: Foo::where('b', 15)->pluck('a')->all();