# High query overhead with Rainlab Translate for a dropdown menu

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I have a model called `Area` which contains a list of area names that I need to populate a dropdown. The list is translated using the Rainlab Translate plugin.

If I just do a straightforward `Area::lists()` then the list is not translated. However, if I do `Area::get()->lists()` then it is translated but one query is run on the `rainlab_translate_attributes` table for every single item in the dropdown, causing ~100 queries to run and a 1.5s request duration.

**Model**

```
<?php namespace Namespace\PluginName\Models;

use Model;

class Area extends Model
{
    public $implement = ['RainLab.Translate.Behaviors.TranslatableModel'];

    public $translatable = ['name'];

    // .... 
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group {{ errors.first('location_id') ? 'has-error' }}">
    {{ form_label('area_id','Area') }}
    {{ form_select('area_id', {'': 'Select...'} + area, null, {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Select...'}) }}
    <small class="text-danger" data-validate-for="area_id"></small>
</div>
```

**Component Option #1** (fast query but items don't get translated)

```
public function areas() {
    return Area::lists('name','id');
}
```

**Component Option #2** (items translated but ~100 queries and very slow)

```
public function areas() {
    return Area::get()->lists('name','id');
}
```

In other similar situations I would add `public $with = ['relation']` but the `rainlab_translate_attributes` table doesn't seem to have a model that I could related the `Area` model to.

**UPDATE**

I have created the following functions in my `Area.php` model:

```
public static function listAreas()
{
    $areas = Cache::rememberForever("all:" . App::getLocale()  , function() {
        return self::
        whereNotNull('iso3166_2')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
    });

    return  self::makeCollection( $areas ) ;
}

public static function makeCollection ( array $models = [] )
{
    return self::hydrate( $models );
}
```

...and then in my component, I have tried:

`$areas = Area::listAreas();` <-- this reads cached data immedately

`$areas->lists('name','id');` <-- this causes a new query to be generated for every item in the collection, here's an example of one query:

`select * from`rainlab_translate_attributes`where`locale`= 'th' and`model_id`= '1275' and`model_type`= 'Namespace\PluginName\Models\Area' limit 1`

I have verified that `App::getLocale()` is correctly set as `th`

Comment: have you considered caching your query ?

Comment: Unfortunately caching the query wouldn't help because it would only cache the original query (which is only taking 50ms anyway) and not the subsequent queries that are called automatically to handle the translations.

Comment: Actually I am caching the model, its translated attributes and relations. I'm using Redis, for example you can prefix the active locale to the cache key and have multiple versions cached.

Comment: Added an asnwer hope it helps. Cheers

Comment: try loading your model with `translations` relation.  `protected $with = ['translations'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same requirements and solved it using **caching** . If you don't want to cache your queries ignore this answer but I think you should consider it.

1) Make sure your `RainLab Translator` is configured, so when using `App::getLocale()` returns the Translator's active locale not Laravel's.

2) Create a method in your model for front-end usage. The purpose is to cache the Model / Relations & Translated Attributes.

E.g AreaModel.php

```
public static function listAreas()
{
       $areas = Cache::tags([  'areas' ])
            ->rememberForever(  "all:" . App::getLocale()  , function() {
                return self::
                    with(['relation_model_name']) // Fetch the Relation
                    ->get()
                    ->toArray();
            });

    return  self::makeCollection( $areas ) ;
}

public static function makeCollection ( array $models = [] )
{
    return self::hydrate( $models );
}
```

a) Here we are cahcing the query with a key that includes the active locale

b) We are adding `with` for related models

c) We just cache the whole collection ( No `pluck` / `lists` ) and converting back to eloquent model instance.

The advantages is that now in your component `Area::listAreas();` will return the cached collections and you can manipulated like any other.

```
$areas = Area::listAreas(); // collection ( Area + Relation )

$dropdown = $areas->pluck('name', 'id'); // get Dropdown values for Areas...
```

Some Consideration is to clear the cache ( Delete Cache Tag / Key ) every time a record is Updates, Added or Deleted ( Model + Relations ) .

Below Screenshots of Redis Cache Store for a `Store Model` and its relation model `Business Type`;

[image: E.g of Store Model - EN]
[image: E.g of Store Model - ES]

**Update** :

First I apologize for using Redis in my example assuming everyone does. The Original post should have been more focused on the implementation. Please don't copy / paste code as I did.

a) In my original answer I posted code using the `hydrate()` method to create an exisiting model instance from the cached records. It was confusing & not necesary but I doubt it has to do with the related queries to the rainlab translate. ( Needs confirmation )

b)  `return self::whereNotNull('iso3166_2')->get()->lists('name','id')` is more than enough to cache Areas records.

c) In my comment I used `pluck` because `lists` is deprecated. `pluck` returns a collection - See [here](https://octobercms.com/support/article/rn-9) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857297/how-to-return-an-array-instead-of-a-collection-in-laravel)

```
$areas = self::whereNotNull('iso3166_2')->pluck('name', 'id') ; // collection
$areas->toArray();
```

I haven't tried the file-based caching yet with October and not sure about its behavior Vs Redis.

Again, Some Considerations ;

a) Please name your cache key to something unique and meaningful, in my post `all + locale` was related to a cache tag `areas` . e.g. `areas.iso3166_2.locale` ( Avoid overrides )

b) Add Cache::forget('key'); in your models `afterSave` & `afterDelete` methods

c) If you are caching related models also be careful to clear the cache when they change.

Comment: thank you for this -- I have it partially working in that I can call `$areas = Area::listAreas();` and it caches it the first time and then ready it from the cache the second time. I have verified that the correct translated values are present too. However, the unexpected behaviour is that if I run `$areas->pluck('name', 'id');` or `$areas->lists('name', 'id');` then it is automatically queries the rainlab translation table again. I don't understand why it is doing this when the data is cached.

Comment: Are you sure the query is related to the Area Model ? Did you check you're not calling the model from other code ? Can you post your `listAreas` method ?

Comment: thank you for your reply -- I have updated the original question to show the code I have tried. Please note that I am using file-based cache and not redis so I had to remove the tags part.

Comment: What if you just do return self::whereNotNull('iso3166_2')->pluck('name','id'): in your method and forget about 'hydrate' I posted it in my answer but it's not necessary for this case it was an example.

Comment: Ok, that works! I had to leave `get()` in there as well though, otherwise the translation didn't happen. So I did `return self::whereNotNull('iso3166_2')->get()->lists('name','id')` inside the `Cache` closure and it works perfectly. Thank you! Do you want to update the answer so that I can mark it correct?

Comment: @Joseph Glad it helps - Answer Updated. You actually did most of the work. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer and for adding the reminder about clearing the cache on `afterSave` and `afterDelete` - I have marked the answer correct now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fire `JOIN` **manually** I guess, there seems `no functionality available for collection`.

```
$locale = 'de';
$query = \HardikSatasiya\DemoTest\Models\Relation::query();

$query->select($query->getModel()->getTable() .'.*');
$query->addSelect('rainlab_translate_attributes.attribute_data');
$query->leftJoin('rainlab_translate_attributes', function($join) use ($locale, $query) {
    $join
        ->on(\Db::raw(\DbDongle::cast($query->getModel()->getQualifiedKeyName(), 'TEXT')), '=', 'rainlab_translate_attributes.model_id')
        ->where('rainlab_translate_attributes.model_type', '=', get_class($query->getModel()))
        ->where('rainlab_translate_attributes.locale', '=', $locale)
    ;
});

$data = $query->get();
$translatedArray = [];
foreach ($data as $value) {
    if(is_null($value->attribute_data)) {
        $translatedArray[$value->id] = $value->name;
    }
    else {
        $translations = json_decode($value->attribute_data);
        $translatedArray[$value->id] = $translations->name;
    }

}
dd($translatedArray);
```

may be this will help you.

Comment: Hello again @Hardik Satasiya thank you for replying to my issue and sorry for the delay in replying. Your solution looks interesting but I am unsure about where to implement this code to use it in the front end. Does it belong in the component or model?

Comment: I guess you can write this code inside `public static function listAreas(){ ..here...}` and return translated options. Caching is ok but it can be useful for static data, data which can be changed at some time may create issue sometimes not all time :)

Comment: I think that in this particular case (given that I am just dealing with a list of areas that will only change if the government reassigns the district names) caching is the best option. However, your suggestion will be highly valuable for other cases and I will keep a note of it. I have also upvoted it. Thank you very much for your help @Hardik Satasiya !

Answer (score 0):

Another idea that could affect speed (if not number of queries) - indexing model's name property:

```
public $translatable = [
    ['name', 'index' => true]
];
```

Reference: https://github.com/rainlab/translate-plugin#indexed-attributes

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately adding the index does not appear to have affected the speed of the queries.